How to reset Multi Bloc provider in the root of the Flutter widget tree when logging out the user
 return HiveListener(
        box: Hive.box('SETTINGS'),
        builder: (bx) {
          return MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => ParentsBottomNavCubit()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => TeacherBottomNavCubit()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => AuthBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => TeacherSubjectBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => HomeWorkBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => SubjectBloc(), lazy: true),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => ProfileBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => EventBloc(), lazy: true),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => FeesBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => TeacherAttendanceBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => StudentBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => FeedbackBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => RoutineBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => SummaryBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => StudentAttendanceHistoryBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => AwardsBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => StudentBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => WeeklyHomeworkBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => StudentLeaderboardBloc()),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => ChatBloc()),
            ],
            child: MaterialApp.router(
              title: 'Home Tracking',
              localizationsDelegates: const [
                AppLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
              ],
              locale: Locale(
                  Hive.box('SETTINGS').get('language', defaultValue: 'en')),
              supportedLocales: const [
                Locale('en'),
                Locale('ne'),
              ],
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              routerConfig: AppRoutes.appRouter,
              theme: AppThemeData.lightModeThemeData(context),
            ),
          );
        });

Logging out users is not resetting the value of states, while logging user out it give error.
I tried resetting all the bloc by emitting them to initial state but it give error.
please help me to solve this problem.

what do you mean by: "I tried resetting all the bloc by emitting them to initial state but it give error."
what kind of error? this error occurs in all bloc's or in specific?

All the bloc are reset when the user logout. Then the token is cleared. After that a function is called emitting all the bloc states to initial state. After emitting all the states to initial it goes to login page but all pages initial states is called triggering event that gets data and it give error. How do I solve this problem?

All blocs emits its error states

So, you got an error not because of internal bloc work, but because of the logic of the app goes wrong after user log out - "all pages initial states is called triggering event that gets data". why?
when user first launches app before login, app behavior is the same or he must login first?

if app behavioru is: user should login first and then all data will be triggered, then this is main issue. then you should provide more code of AuthBloc and where user goes from login page to next page

@valdyslav I posted the code for AuthBloc below. Please help me to fix the error. Thank You

provide code of the page where you hanle AuthLoaded event.
Error text will be helpfull also

error are given by other pages which are not related to the login or the page where there is log out button.

@valdyslav Help me
